# Pre-emphasis in speech processing using android

Tags: android, filtering, signal-processing, speech-recognition, mfcc

I'm working on an application where i need to implement Mel Frequency Cepstral Coefficients (MFCC) for speech recognition.

The first step in MFCC is to apply Pre-Emphasis

Pre-Emphasis will increase the energy of signal at higher frequency.
Because the low frequency band is occupied by sounds which are useless/harmful for speech recognition.

I found this equation for this process:

```
 Y[n]=X[n]−0.95⋅X[n−1]
```

My question is should i just simply apply this equation on the original signal?? So that it would increase the energy of the signal at higher frequency. Or should i apply a certain filter on the input signal before applying this equation? and if so, how would i program it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That equation is already the pre-emphasis filter.

In c-code an implementation could looks like this:

```
float last_input = 0;

float filter (float input)
{
  float output = input - 0.95 * last_input;
  last_input = input;
  return output;
}
```

Here is the frequency response of the filter, assuming a sample-rate of 44.1 kHz:

[image: Frequency response]

Comment: so i am going to input the entire signal into this filter?? or should i just input the high frequency components of the original signal into this filter??,, in order to increase the energy of the high frequency components of original signal??

Comment: Run the entire signal through the filter.

Comment: thanx  Nils Pipenbrinck for your help :)